# Kafka state stores forget old data?

Tags: apache-kafka, retention

I try to query my local window state stores like this:

```
long timeFrom = 0;
long timeTo = System.currentTimeMillis();
WindowStoreIterator<Long> iterator = windowStore.fetch("topic name", timeFrom, timeTo);
```

I only get around about 36 hours of windowed data back, but would like to get far back in the past.

I tried to configure the retention in several ways, and also restarted my kafka server and zookeeper:

in config/server.properties:
log.retention.hours=87600

bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk.yoursite.com --alter --topic topicName --config retention.ms=86400000

Still Kafka does not keep old data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for window retention, not log retention. If so, you can find out how to configure this to your liking here http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#windowing

Comment: funny thing, when defining this window retention, data from the past appear immediately - so they have never been deleted, but just not been fetched

Comment: yeah it's the window retention, so the data still exists in the change log to pull up, but you have to tell it to go get it :)

Answer (score 0):

check this setting `log.retention.bytes` to see if you're deleting data after a certain size. Retention policy can also be size based.

Comment: When you consume using consumer are you able to see the old data?

Comment: the log.retention.bytes was not set at all and I guess it does not have a default. To be sure I set it now and will see what happens...

Comment: @mrnakumar I did not check yet.

Comment: Can you please check this? This will help us identify where the problem is, in Kafka or streams code itself